# Create a Paint program!

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, interactive

## Introduction

One day, you were showing your kid how to draw on a computer. You type `mspaint.exe` in the run bar. To your horror, it says "No items match your search". You must create a simple version of paint so your kid can draw!

## Challenge

You must create a simple drawing program. To do this, open a white display window (larger than 99x99 pixels). Anytime the mouse is pressed down, change the pixel that the mouse is on to black.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Does it need to be pixels? or can it be 99x99 squares?

Comment: How long does it need to run for?

Comment: When TI-Basic's `Pen` does exactly this :o

Comment: @Riker it should run for at least 10 seconds, preferably forever

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk it should be pixels, unless it would add 50 bytes or more to do so. also, **larger** than 99x99

Comment: Is larger than 99×99 just so we have to use three digits in decimal notation for each dimension? Would 99×100 or 100×99 be valid?

Comment: @Xufox It is that size so that it is big enough to be an (okay) drawing program. No, those would not be valid.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

## 8086 machine code, <s>32 31 28</s> 26 bytes

```
00000000  b8 0f 00 cd 10 b8 02 10  ba 18 01 cd 10 b8 03 00  |................|
00000010  cd 33 4b b8 01 0c eb f3  3f 00                    |.3K.....?.|
0000001a
```

Assumes the presence of a VGA graphics card, and any Microsoft-compatible mouse driver.

-2 bytes thanks to @berendi!

[image: screenshot]

#### How it works:

```
            |   org 0x100
            |   use16
b8 0f 00    |       mov ax, 0x000f      ; set screen mode: 640x350 monochrome
cd 10       |       int 0x10            ; call video bios
b8 02 10    |       mov ax, 0x1002      ; set palette
ba 18 01    |       mov dx, palette     ; pointer to palette data
cd 10       |   @@: int 0x10            ; call video bios
b8 03 00    |       mov ax, 0x0003      ; get mouse position in (CX, DX) and button status in BL
cd 33       |       int 0x33            ; call mouse driver
4b          |       dec bx              ; if no buttons pressed, --BX = 0xFFFF (invalid page)
b8 01 0c    |       mov ax, 0x0c01      ; plot pixel with color AL at (CX, DX) in page BH
eb f3       |       jmp @b              ; repeat
3f 00       |   palette db 0x3f, 0x00   ; palette in 2:2:2 rgb. color 0 = white, 1 = black.
            |                           ; this should be a 17-byte struct, but we only care about the first two colors here
```

That's all there is to it. No magic involved, just a few function calls.

Comment: Setting up the palette colors takes 10 bytes here. I wonder if there's a shorter way to do it?

Comment: Would you be able to make it shorter by using CGA rather than VGA?

Comment: The CGA has no way to change indivitual palette colors, as far as I can tell. You could change the background color to white, but it won't let you draw black pixels.

Comment: Clean, clear, and clever code. Very nicely done! I don't see anywhere this can be further optimized for size. For some reason, when I tried this using the CuteMouse driver, this draws *without* the mouse button having to be held down, but that may just be an issue with CuteMouse not being 100% Microsoft-compatible. Which driver did you use for testing?

Comment: Only tested on Dosbox so far, which has a mouse driver built-in. I can try it on a dos machine with Cutemouse tomorrow. The trick with "dec bx" to set the page number assumes the reserved bits in bx to be clear, that assumption may be incorrect. Or perhaps the video bios doesn't perform proper bounds checking on the page number.

Comment: Hmm. After running the code with a debugger (good old DEBUG.COM, of course!), it appears it's not a problem with the CuteMouse driver. Without a button held down, `INT 33h` is returning 0 in `BX`, and this gets decremented to FFFFh as expected, but a line is still being drawn. Perhaps this is because mode 11h only has one video page, and the invalid page number is automatically being fixed up? I'm testing on VM VirtualBox, so maybe that's something its BIOS implementation is doing.

Comment: Oh that's definitely a BIOS issue. I don't think it should do anything if the page number is invalid. I have a disassembled VGA-compatible bios somewhere, again, I can check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Looks like VirtualBox is to blame here, it simply ignores the page number altogether: https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices/Graphics/BIOS/vgabios.c#L1350

Comment: Also you're right in that mode 0x11 isn't guaranteed to have multiple pages. I'll change it to use mode 0x0F which should have at least two.

Comment: Bill Atkinson himself would be proud of this.  Splendid work.

Comment: **-2 bytes** remove the last `int 0x10`, `jmp` back to the second `int 0x10` instead. Offset in `jmp` remains the same, adjust address in `mov dx`

Comment: Oooh, nice catch! That is so obvious once you see it. Thank you!

Comment: Nah, Bill Atkinson is [not a hacker](http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=Were_Not_Hackers!.txt). :-) @wossname

Comment: this answer is now at 86 votes

Answer (score 27):

## Scratch, 10 Scratch bytes

[image]

Scratch was practically designed for things like this.

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/156553434)

Comment: Does this actually do pixels? Also, if you click the mouse fast vs holding it for a bit, it produces different results (without moving it of course). I think that invalidates this.

Comment: @Riker This produces pixels. The holding thing is because Scratch by default runs at the screen refresh rate, so it takes a bit to detect that the mouse is down.

Comment: I highly doubt it does pixels, as I can see antialiasing around the edges.

Comment: Pen size is set to 1 by default which is 1 pixel. I can't control the antialiasing as it is automatically applied.

Comment: This is not 10 Scratch bytes, according to the scoring we currently use.

Comment: You should probably use the scratchblocks app to convert to text, or the SB2 file size.

Comment: I'm using the scoring that I used with earlier Scratch answers. Can someone please link me to the current scoring? @Okx

Comment: @Mendeleev I'm not certain, but he's probably referring to this [Scratch scoring system](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5013/5029).

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer That is the top voted answer on the meta question

Answer (score 19):

## HTML + JavaScript (ES6), <strike>66 64</strike> 62 bytes

**HTML**

```
<canvas id=c>
```

**JavaScript**

```
onclick=e=>c.getContext`2d`.fillRect(e.x,e.y,1,1)
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Gustavo Rodrigues and 2 bytes from Shaggy.

```js
onclick=e=>c.getContext`2d`.fillRect(e.x,e.y,1,1)
```

```css
/* This css isn't needed for the program to work. */
*{margin: 0}
#c{border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

Comment: How about `<canvas id=c>`?

Comment: This actually puts the dot not where my cursor goes, but to the bottom right of the arrow. Is this intentional?

Comment: Save 2 bytes by dropping the `c.` from the start of your JS. @Anoplexian, that's the default body `margin` throwing things off by a few pixels.

Comment: How do I make this work? I'm clicking in the result area and it's not doing anything.

Comment: And you can save a 3rd bytes by omitting the closing `>` from your HTML.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks for both the suggestions, but dropping the `>` from the html didn't seem to work.

Comment: That seems to be something particular to Stack Snippets; if you give it a try on JSFiddle, for example, it'll work.

Comment: @Anoplexian That's a known issue; there's no reliable way to get the relative position of the mouse cursor on an element (short of large, browser-specific functions that fail when a new type of CSS padding is introduced).

Answer (score 19):

### C + Win32, <s>209</s> <s>200</s> <s>195</s> <s>178</s> 159 bytes

- 2022 Update: Saved 19 bytes by removing `#include <windows.h>`.

```c
short m[9];main(h){for(h=CreateWindowExA(0,"EDIT","",1<<28,0,0,199,199,0);GetMessageA(m,h,0,0);m[4]^513?DispatchMessageA(m):SetPixel(GetDC(h),m[12],m[13],0));}
```

Thanks, Cody and Quentin! I was hoping to get rid of the `#include <windows.h>` but this leads to all sort of errors. At least it is working correctly with multiple monitors...

Saved 17 bytes thanks to inspiration by [@c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)!!!

[image]

Comment: I can't test right now, bu I think you can merge the declaration of `h` into the `for` initializer to save two bytes :)

Comment: I realize this is code golf and it may be desirable here, but `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` are *not* the correct way to extract cursor coordinates from a packed `LPARAM`. You should be using `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM`, otherwise you will get wrong results with multiple monitors.

Comment: @Quentin, that will work in c++ but not in c. I could have used c++ but then I would have written `int main` which would have added 4 more bytes.

Comment: @Cody, Fair comment. I don't have a multi monitor system to test but do you think using `(short)LOWORD()` and `(short)HIWORD()` would solve the issue?

Comment: What Quentin suggested works fine in any modern version of C, including C99. Of course, you are using Microsoft's C compiler, which is stuck back in C89/90, with its demented variable scoping rules. C89 is also why you're allowed to omit the `main` function's return type (because of the implicit-`int` rule). Only problem is, omitting the `return 0;` causes undefined behavior in C89 and MSVC. In C99 and C++, you need a return type for `main`, but the `return 0;` is implicit and thus unnecessary. Well, the language wasn't made for code golfing. :-)

Comment: And sure, an explicit cast to signed `short` will work. The deal is just that the coordinates are actually *signed* values, but the `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` macros treat them as *unsigned* values, which means you'll get incorrect coordinates when you have multiple monitors, since the virtual desktop always has the origin (0, 0) at the top-left of the *primary* monitor, and if a secondary monitor is to the left of and/or the top of the primary monitor, it will have negative coordinates. But `(short)LOWORD` is not only less readable/idiomatic than the recommended macro, but is also more characters!

Comment: @CodyGray yep, didn't realize that this was probably MSVC. Note that GCC is great for golfing, as it can accept a mixture of pretty much every C dialect without complaining too much.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think I saw someone drawing pictures on the console before.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one is more concerned with the blinking caret in the window :-)

Comment: There shouldn't be a blinking caret. In fact, there shouldn't be a command prompt appearing at all. If there is, that suggests that you have the linker misconfigured. You shouldn't be targeting the Console subsystem; you are creating a Win32 app.

Answer (score 10):

## Processing, <s>98</s> 79 bytes

*19 bytes saved thanks to @dzaima*

```processing
void setup(){background(-1);}void draw(){if(mousePressed)point(mouseX,mouseY);}
```

#### Explanation (outdated)

```processing
void setup() {
  size(100,100);            // size of the sketch
  background(-1);           // set the background to white
                            // 1 byte shorter than background(255);
}

void draw(){}               // required for mousePressed to work

void mousePressed() {       // function that is called whenever the mouse is pressed
  point(mouseX, mouseY);    // draw a point at the mouse's coordinates
                            // the colour is set to black as default
}
```

[image: clicketty click]

Comment: @dzaima I did not know the `size(100,100);` does not have to be mentioned, thanks! (also I don't know why I did not see the `if(mousePressed)` bit)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript ES6, 126 bytes

Tested in chrome.

```
onclick=e=>document.body.outerHTML+=`<a style=position:fixed;top:${e.y}px;left:${e.x}px;width:1px;height:1px;background:#000>`
```

#### Try it online!

```js
onclick=e=>document.body.outerHTML+=`<a style=position:fixed;top:${e.y}px;left:${e.x}px;width:1px;height:1px;background:#000>`
```

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <s>189</s> <s>184</s> <s>170</s> 169 bytes

```
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game
main=play FullScreen white 9[]Pictures(#)(\_->id)
EventKey(MouseButton LeftButton)Down _(x,y)#l=Translate x y(Circle 1):l
_#l=l
```

This uses the `Gloss` library (v1.11). It opens a full screen window and paints black pixels (in fact circles with radius 1) by pressing the left mouse button. Press `ESC` to exit.

How it works:

```
play                 -- handles the whole event handling, screen update, etc. process
    FullScreen       -- use a full screen window
    white            -- use a white background
    9                -- 9 simulation steps per second (see simulation handler below)
    []               -- the initial world state, an emtpy list of circles
    Pictures         -- a function to turn the world state into a picture.
                     -- The world state is a list of translated circles and
                     -- "Pictures" turns this list into a single picture
    (#)              -- event handler, see below
    (\_->id)         -- simulation step handler. Ignore time tick and return the
                     -- world state unchanged. More readable: "\tick world -> world"

EventKey ... # l=... -- if the left mouse button is pressed, add a circle with
                     -- radius 1 translated to the current position of the mouse
                     -- to the world state
_#l=l                -- on all other events do nothing
```

Edit: @ceased to turn counterclockwis told me about the newst version of gloss which saves 5 bytes when using full screen windows. Thanks!

Comment: [`FullScreen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.11.1.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Display.html#v:FullScreen) is nullary in gloss>=1.11, reducing the score by 5. (I'm getting an error `unknown GLUT entry glutInit` though, but probably my glut setup just doesn't work; never used it on this machine.)

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis: ah, thanks for the hint. I had 1.10.2.3 on my system and now updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 5):

## SmileBASIC 2, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

This one runs in SmileBASIC's daddy, Petit Computer (and is <s>one</s> two byte shorter.)

```
PNLTYPE"OFF
GPAGE 1GCLS 15@A
GPSET TCHX,TCHY
GOTO@A
```

Explanation:

```
PNLTYPE"OFF       'turn off keyboard
GPAGE 1           'set graphics to lower screen
GCLS 15           'clear with color 15 (white)
@A                'loop begin
GPSET TCHX,TCHY   'set black pixel at draw location
GOTO@A            'loop
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by doing `GPSET TCHX,TCHY:GOTO@A` since the default color is 0 (transparent).

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript + jQuery 138 bytes

```
d=$(document.body).click((e)=>d.append("<div style='background:black;width:5;height:5;position:fixed;top:"+e.pageY+";left:"+e.pageX+"'>"))
```

[Check it out online!](http://neil.computer/golf/paint.php)

Adding click and drag support would be simple, you'd set a variable, however, per the instructions and to shorten code, it is not supported, "Anytime the mouse is pressed down, change the pixel that the mouse is on to black".  I interpretted the instruction as a `click` event.

Comment: Hiya! Next time, you should undelete your old answer instead of making a new answer. Also, I'm afraid that this must work in a specified environment--if this is vanilla javascript, you'll have to include the byte count of jQuery with your submission. You could call this submission "JavaScript + jQuery", and that would be fine: there you could assume jQuery is installed. As this answer currently stands, its more of a "HTML" answer,n ot a javascript one.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I'll make sure to do that next time.  I updated the answer using your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

## SpecBAS - <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```
1 CLS 15 
2 IF MOUSEBTN=1 THEN PLOT MOUSEx,MOUSEy
3 GO TO 2
```

Black is already the default pen colour, but the background is usually a nasty shade of grey, so `CLS 15` sets it to bright white.

[image]

Comment: Most Basic variants don't require a space between the command number and the code on that line.

Comment: SpecBAS adds all the spaces after you hit return (including `GOTO` becoming `GO TO`)

Comment: But can you remove the spaces, and still have it run fine? If so, you don't count them.

Comment: If the user doesn't mind only painting with black, why would he mind a grey background?

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, <s>70</s> <s>58</s> 53 Bytes

```
XSCREEN 4GCLS-1@L
TOUCH OUT,X,Y
GPSET X,Y+240,0GOTO@L
```

Explained:

```
XSCREEN 4 'display one graphics page on both screens
GCLS -1 'fill screen with white
@L 'loop
TOUCH OUT,X,Y 'get touch location
GPSET X,Y+240,0 'draw black pixel at touch position, offset by the height of the top screen.
GOTO @L 'loop
```

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, <s>91</s> 71 bytes

-20 bytes thanks to @cfrick for pointing out that I can use `use` to shrink my importing.

```clj
(use 'quil.core)(defsketch P :mouse-dragged #(point(mouse-x)(mouse-y)))
```

Uses the [Quil](http://quil.info/) library. Draws a dot whenever the mouse is dragged.

Basically the Processing answer, since Quil is a Processing wrapper for Clojure.

```clj
(q/defsketch P ; Start a new drawing
             
             :mouse-dragged ; Attach a mouse drag listener
             ; that draws a point at the current mouse location
             #(q/point (q/mouse-x) (q/mouse-y)))
```

[image]

Comment: 71: `(use 'quil.core)(defsketch P :mouse-dragged #(point(mouse-x)(mouse-y)))`

Comment: @cfrick LOL, I always forget about `use` because it's "not proper". Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## Tcl/Tk, 45 <s>46</s> <s>51</s> <s>57</s>

```
gri [can .c]
bind . <1> {.c cr o %x %y %x %y}
```

[image: pentagram]

Comment: That is one fugly pentogram 

Comment: @JohanduToit: Don't you like stars?

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, 62 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that allows the user to draw on the any sheet by simply selecting it

```vb
Cells.RowHeight=48:Do:DoEvents:Selection.Interior.Color=0:Loop
```

## Sample Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 353 bytes

```
import java.awt.*;import java.awt.event.*;class M{static int x,y;public static void main(String[]a){Frame f=new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);}};f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){x=e.getX();y=e.getY();f.repaint(x,y,1,1);}});f.setBackground(Color.WHITE);f.resize(500,500);f.show();}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class M {
    //store the last point
    static int x, y;
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Frame f = new Frame() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            }
        }
        f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
                //repaint only the "new pixel"
                f.repaint(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        });
        //default background is grey
        f.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.resize(500, 500);
        f.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 1 byte

```
Pt-Change(
```

I'm sure that most of you with TI calcs thought of the `Pen` command, but it turns out that it's not tokenized so it would make most sense to count that as 3 bytes. You can read about the interactive version of `Pt-Change(` at http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/pt-change

Comment: This does not answer the challenge: TI calcs can’t handle mouse input, as far as I know.

Comment: @Grimy If you insist you can always use the usb8x library to get USB mouse input instead. But I'm sure that the default cursor navigation will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

## Python2 *and* Python3, 82 bytes (or 77?)

```
from turtle import *;up();onscreenclick(lambda x,y: goto(x,y)or dot(1));mainloop()
```

Using the Turtle module, this isn't too bad :)

Ungolfed:

```
import turtle
turtle.up()

def fun(x, y):
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.dot(1)

turtle.onscreenclick(fun)
turtle.mainloop()
```

If it's OK to have lines between the dots, you can actually save 5 bytes:

```
from turtle import *;onscreenclick(lambda x,y: goto(x,y)or dot(1));mainloop()
```

Comment: from turtle import *;up();onclick(lambda *x:goto(*x)or dot(1));done()

Comment: That's 70 bytes

Answer (score 1):

### HTML + Javascript, <s>152</s> 148 bytes

```
<body onclick="document.body.innerHTML+='<x style=position:fixed;width:1;height:1;left:'+event.clientX+';top:'+event.clientY+';background:#000;>'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Turing](http://compsci.ca/holtsoft/), 77 bytes

```
var x,y,b:int loop mousewhere(x,y,b)if b=1then drawdot(x,y,1)end if end loop
```

Ungolfed:

```
var x,y,b : int      
loop
  mousewhere(x,y,b)  % Set (x,y) to mouse co-ords, and b to 1 or 0 indicating if the button is pressed
  if b=1 then
    drawdot(x,y,1)  % Draw a black pixel at (x,y)
  end if
end loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML + CSS + JavaScript (ES6), 8 + 31 + 64 = 103 bytes

Fun with CSS `box-shadow`!

```js
s='0 0 0',onclick=e=>p.style.boxShadow=s+=`,${e.x}px ${e.y}px 0`
```

```css
*{margin:0;width:1px;height:1px
```

```html
<p id=p>
```

## HTML + CSS + JavaScript (ES6), 8 + 22 + 69 = 99 bytes

This one attempts to offset the default `margin` of the `<body>` element, but it may be different across browsers and user agent stylesheets. Tested successfully in Chrome.

```js
s='0 0 0',onclick=e=>p.style.boxShadow=s+=`,${e.x-8}px ${e.y-16}px 0`
```

```css
*{width:1px;height:1px
```

```html
<p id=p>
```

## HTML + CSS + JavaScript (ES6), 8 + 18 + 69 = 95 bytes

Pixels in this one may appear bigger as they are drawn at half-pixel coordinates.

```js
s='0 0 0',onclick=e=>p.style.boxShadow=s+=`,${e.x}px ${e.y}px 0 .5px`
```

```css
*{margin:0;width:0
```

```html
<p id=p>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua (love2d Framework), 180 bytes

golfed version

```lua
l=love v,g,m,p=255,l.graphics,l.mouse,{}d=m.isDown function l.draw()g.setBackgroundColor(v,v,v)if d(1)or d(2)then p[#p+1],p[#p+2]=m.getPosition()end g.setColor(0,0,0)g.points(p)end
```

ungolfed

```lua
l=love 
v,g,m,p=255,l.graphics,l.mouse,{}
d=m.isDown 
function l.draw()
  g.setBackgroundColor(v,v,v)
  if d(1)or d(2)then 
    p[#p+1],p[#p+2]=m.getPosition()
  end 
  g.setColor(0,0,0)
  g.points(p)
end
```

quite easy how it works.
First a few initialisations to make things shorter.
After it it will check the mous is clicked and saves the points to the array.
After that it draws the points.Also it sets the color to white& black cause default is the other way around :)

And here comes the picture:

[image]

Comment: Believe it or not, I came here to post an answer using Love2d as I only recently found out about it and love it, so +1 for the nice effort! Anyway, I think you can shorten it down a bit more as like this: `l=love v,g,m,p=255,l.graphics,l.mouse,{}function l.draw()g.setBackgroundColor(v,v,v)if m.isDown(1)then p[#p+1],p[#p+2]=m.getPosition()end g.setColor(0,0,0)g.points(p)end` which results into 169 bytes!

Comment: I came here kind of the same reason, nice to see that there are other people out here who know it :D  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

### Processing, 65 bytes

```
void draw(){if(mousePressed)line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);}
```

[image: minimal draw]

Answer (score 1):

## glslsandbox 232 bytes

Old post but found this interesting.
Since processing already been done I decided to do something different.

This draws whether the mouse is pressed or not, so not what pydude asked for but almost.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision lowp float;
#endif
uniform float time;uniform vec2 mouse,resolution;uniform sampler2D t;void main(){vec2 f=gl_FragCoord.xy,r=resolution;gl_FragColor=vec4(time<2.||length(f-mouse*r)>2.&&texture2D(t,f/r).x>.1);}
```

[Try it on glslsandbox](http://glslsandbox.com/e#43844.0)

Answer (score 0):

**Processing, 93 bytes, 91 bytes if spaces don't count**

```
void setup(){size(100,100);background(-1);}void draw(){if(mousePressed) point(mouseX,mouseY);}
```

Comment: In PPCG, if not mentioned in the challenge, spaces and everything count as normal (as bytes in the encoding of choice, by default UTF-8). So your score would be 92 bytes as the 1st space can't be removed without breaking the program, but the second space can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

### UCBlogo with wxWidgets, 65 bytes

```
setbg 7
setpc 0
ht
pu
make "buttonact[setpos clickpos pd fd 1 pu]
```

Explanation (the code assigned to the variable `buttonact` is executed on each button click):

```
SetBackground 7 ; white
SetPenColor 0 ; black
HideTurtle
PenUp
make "buttonact [
  SetPos ClickPos
  PenDown
  Forward 1
  PenUp
]
```

At least, I think this works. It should according to the [documentation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/usermanual), but apparently the `buttonact` variable only works in a wxWidgets build and I'm struggling to build UCBLogo with wxWidgets on a modern Linux (waddyamean you can't cast a pointer to `int` and back?).

### UCBlogo without wxWidgets, 73 bytes

To see the intended effect, you can run this longer version with an infinite loop.

```
setbg 7 setpc 0 ht pu
while[1=1][setpos mousepos if[button?][pd] fd 1 pu]
```

But this crashes `ucblogo` on my machine... Looks like a race condition.

### UCBlogo, actually working on my machine, 80 bytes

```
setbg 7 setpc 0 ht pu
while[1=1][setpos mousepos if[button?][pd] fd 1 pu wait 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 37 bytes

```apl
P5.draw←{P5.Lm.p:P5.G.pt P5.mx P5.my}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P8BUL6UosfxR24RqINMnV6/ACki76xWUKADp3AowWVn7/z8A)

Machine code is OP.